# Testcase is not getting failed when we use assert inside promise

Tags: javascript, protractor

Below is my code. Test-case is getting passed whether my actual is equal to expected or not equal.It is just showing warning message when it is not equal but my test-case is shown in green .I cant see any failure message in report.

Code:

```
this.VerifyAccountHolder=async function(){
 var testPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(elementAccount.isPresent());
    }, 200);

});
var result = await testPromise;
assert.equal(result,true,"wrong result");
```

Warning message:

> (node:8784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected false to equal
>   true (node:8784) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the  Nodejs process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

how to avoid this warning

> I want to display the assertion error in report.I'm new to JavaScript protractor framework.

Comment: This looks like it might be a page object function?  If so, [Avoid using expect() in page objects](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this whole function by removing the promise entirely. I'm really not sure why you need `setTimeout` either. The element is going to present or it isn't. You could probably use `ExpectedConditions.presenceOf()` with `browser.wait()` but this seems redundant to me. As much as I hate to suggest this, if you REALLY must wait for 200ms before checking the element is present just use `browser.sleep()`. I would use this as a last resort though. Try getting it to work without any explicit waits if you can.

```
this.VerifyAccountHolder = function() {
    browser.sleep(200); //only use this if you REALLY need it
    return elementAccount.isPresent();    
});
```

And then you should move the assertion to a test instead of keeping it in this function.

```
it('should be present', async () => {
    let result = await pageObjectName.VerifyAccountHolder();
    expect(result).toEqual(true);

    //or if you prefer to keep using a node assertion instead
    //assert.equal(result,true,"element not present");
});
```

Comment: Thanks but testcase is skipping.

Comment: Sorry bro.I made mistake in step description.Your idea is working .Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out. Do you mind accepting the answer?